# Symfony logs not visible in the Symfony profile

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, monolog

I need help. I am using Monolog logger.

```
use Monolog\Logger;

$logger = new Logger('app');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(\dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '\\var/log/dev.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());

$logger->info('My logger is now ready');
```

The problem is that the log is written to the file, but it is not visible in the Symfony profile.

what needs to be done so that the logs are displayed in the Symfony profile??

Comment: Is it possible that your logs are on another request? If you go to "last 10", do you see it?

Comment: why do you dont use the ` LoggerInterface` provided by Symfony itself? Instead of settiging up a logger which should be allready configured and present?

Comment: @Rufinus 
I want a static method "log($text)" so it doesn't suit me LoggerInterface. LoggerInterface i can use in controllers which are extends AbstractController..

Comment: @JulienB. no..i sorted the logs by channel and i dont see them. but they are in the file (var/log/dev.log)

Comment: Is the file with the code you shared executed inside Symfony?

Comment: `LoggerInterface` is not only usable in controllers which extends `AbstractController`. You just have to use dependency injection to get it everywhere. [Symfony documentation - Dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)

Comment: @JulienB. Yes, i use logger in  class MessageHandler implements MessageComponentInterface